# Proxy Pooling System for Scrapy to temporarily stop using slow/timing out proxies

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I've been looking around trying to find a decent pooling system for Scrapy but I can't find anything that has everything I need/want.

I'm looking for a solution to:

#### Rotate proxies

- I'd like them randomly switch between proxies but never selecting the same proxy twice in a row. (Scrapoxy has this)

#### Impersonate Known Browsers

- Impersonate Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge, Safari... etc (Scrapoxy has this)

#### Blacklist Slow Proxies

- If the proxy times out or is slow it should be blacklisted through a series of rules... (Scrapoxy only has blacklisting for number of instances / startups)
- If a proxy is slow (takes over x time) it should be marked as `Slow` and a timestamp should be taken and a counter should be increased.
- If a proxy timeout's it should be marked as `Fail` and a timestamp should be taken and a counter should be increased.
- If a proxy has no slows for 15 minutes after receiving its last slow then the counter & timestamp should be zeroed and the proxy gets returns back to a fresh state.
- If a proxy has no fails for 30 minutes after receiving its last fail then the counter & timestamp should be zeroed and the proxy gets returns back to a fresh state.
- If a proxy is slow 5 times in 1 hour then it should be removed from the pool for 1 hour.
- If a proxy timeout's 5 times in 1 hour then it should be blacklisted for 1 hour
- If a proxy get's blocked twice in 3 hours it should be blacklisted for 12 hours and marked as bad
- If a proxy gets marked as bad twice in 48 hours then it should notify me (email, push bullet... anything)

Anyone know of any such solution (the main feature being the blacklisting of slow/timed out proxies...

Comment: May be this https://github.com/joewhite86/proxy-rotator

Comment: @TarunLalwani That is close but not really good enough because it blocks on one timeout, the way I describe is to try and limit the times they get blacklisted because occasionally a proxy/website can be slow and it should be x amount of times it happens before it gets blacklisted.

Comment: I am not sure if project would match 100% of you requirements and be available to you. You will to find a closest match and then customize it based on your needs

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies ? It may provide some initial help or you could use as a guide to wrtie your own fancy proxy rotating scrapy middleware.

Comment: I've implemented something like this before. basic idea was to scrape a proxy list from https://free-proxy-list.net/ and filter (check if working, timeouts etc.) then randomly rotate between them. List needs to be re-scraped and checked regularly and occasionally proxies will be black listed from your target site so you need a mechanism for back-off / removal from the candidate proxy list

Comment: @stacksonstacks That's a fair bit different. The rotating randomly between them, removing non-working and timing out proxies is all easy to do especially with Scrapy / Scraproxy. It's just the whole process of temporarily marking a proxy as slow/bad, resetting this status if they don't re-offend within a certain period of time and blocking them if they do re-offend x times and also unblocking them after x period of time.

Answer (score 1):

As your polling rules are very specifics, you may code your own, please see the code bellow which implement some part of your rules (you have to implement some other):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import pexpect,time
from random import shuffle

#this func is use to test a single proxy
def test_proxy(ip,port,max_timeout=1):
    child = pexpect.spawn("telnet " + ip + " " +str(port))
    time_send_request=time.time()
    try:
        i=child.expect(["Connected to","Connection refused"], timeout=max_timeout) #max timeout in seconds
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
        i=-1
    if i==0:
        time_request_ok=time.time()
        return {"status":True,"time_to_answer":time_request_ok-time_send_request}
    else:
        return {"status":False,"time_to_answer":max_timeout}


#this func is use to test all the current proxy and update status and apply your custom rules
def update_proxy_list_status(proxy_list):
    for i in range(0,len(proxy_list)):
        print ("testing proxy "+str(i)+" "+proxy_list[i]["ip"]+":"+str(proxy_list[i]["port"]))
        proxy_status = test_proxy(proxy_list[i]["ip"],proxy_list[i]["port"])
        proxy_list[i]["status_ok"]= proxy_status["status"]


        print proxy_status

        #here it is time to treat your own rule to update respective proxy dict

        #~ If a proxy is slow (takes over x time) it should be marked as Slow and a timestamp should be taken and a counter should be increased.
        #~ If a proxy timeout's it should be marked as Fail and a timestamp should be taken and a counter should be increased.
        #~ If a proxy has no slows for 15 minutes after receiving its last slow then the counter & timestamp should be zeroed and the proxy gets returns back to a fresh state.
        #~ If a proxy has no fails for 30 minutes after receiving its last fail then the counter & timestamp should be zeroed and the proxy gets returns back to a fresh state.
        #~ If a proxy is slow 5 times in 1 hour then it should be removed from the pool for 1 hour.
        #~ If a proxy timeout's 5 times in 1 hour then it should be blacklisted for 1 hour
        #~ If a proxy get's blocked twice in 3 hours it should be blacklisted for 12 hours and marked as bad
        #~ If a proxy gets marked as bad twice in 48 hours then it should notify me (email, push bullet... anything)        

        if proxy_status["status"]==True:
            #modify proxy dict with your own rules (adding timestamp, last check time, last down, last up eFIRSTtc...)
            #...
            pass
        else:
            #modify proxy dict with your own rules (adding timestamp, last check time, last down, last up etc...)
            #...
            pass        

    return proxy_list


#this func select a good proxy and do the job
def main():

    #first populate a proxy list | I get those example proxies list from http://free-proxy.cz/en/
    proxy_list=[
        {"ip":"167.99.2.12","port":8080}, #bad proxy
        {"ip":"167.99.2.17","port":8080},
        {"ip":"66.70.160.171","port":1080},
        {"ip":"192.99.220.151","port":8080},
        {"ip":"142.44.137.222","port":80}
        # [...]
    ]



    #this variable is use to keep track of last used proxy (to avoid to use the same one two consecutive time)
    previous_proxy_ip=""

    the_job=True
    while the_job:

        #here we update each proxy status
        proxy_list = update_proxy_list_status(proxy_list)

        #we keep only proxy considered as ok
        good_proxy_list = [d for d in proxy_list if d['status_ok']==True]

        #here you can shuffle the list
        shuffle(good_proxy_list)

        #select a proxy (not same last previous one)
        current_proxy={}
        for i in range(0,len(good_proxy_list)):
            if good_proxy_list[i]["ip"]!=previous_proxy_ip:
                previous_proxy_ip=good_proxy_list[i]["ip"]
                current_proxy=good_proxy_list[i]
                break

        #use this selected proxy to do the job
        print ("the current proxy is: "+str(current_proxy))

        #UPDATE SCRAPY PROXY

        #DO THE SCRAPY JOB
        print "DO MY SCRAPY JOB with the current proxy settings"

        #wait some seconds
        time.sleep(5)

main()
```